# Why can't I write a CSS stylesheet to a file with PHP?

Tags: php, css, fwrite

```
<?php
    $cdata = $_GET['cdata'];
    $cfile = "./output/$ip/output.css";
    $cout = fopen($cfile, 'w') or die("1");
    fwrite($cout, $cdata) or die("Could not write to " . $cfile);
    echo("Wrote CSS to " . $cfile . " successfully.<br />");
    fclose($cout);
?>
```

When I execute this on my web server, it tells me that it was successful (or perchance I didn't catch the error), but it writes part of what I want it to. Here's what I tell it to write (passed in via url as `$_GET['cdata']`):

```
body{background: #000; color: #FFF;}
```

And this is what I get back from the file

```
body{background:
```

Note that there is a space at the end, so I'm assuming the pound (#) is causing issues, but don't know why or how to fix it.

This isn't the entirety of my code, just a snippet, and where I think the error lies. I hope this is enough information, if not please ask and I'll try to throw whatever else in there. Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

Since I was using jQuery's $.post() method to send the data, all I needed to do was wrap the data being sent with encodeURIComponent(), and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks @xbonez for pointing me in the right direction there.

Comment: Because of space in the values . That is why you are getting broken result.

Comment: I was wondering about that. Do you think I could replace " " with "&nbsp;" and that work? EDIT - scratch that, it's going into CSS, not HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode your url property, the # in the url is being treated as a hash and not being sent to the server. e.g.

```
 var args = 'cdata='+encodeURIComponent('body{background: #000; color: #FFF;}');
```

Comment: I thought about that, and it is indeed putting in the url encodings, but PHP.net mentions that urldecode() is performed automatically when using $_GET[''] variables.

Comment: anything after the # symbol is not sent to the server side. So even if `urldecode()` is being performed automatically, the server is never receiving anything beyond the first #. You need to make sure you `urlencode()` too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a quick try - Actually, is there a way I can do this with javascript/jquery? I'm using jquery's $.post() method to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

Get requests are gettings values from the url. You might want to base64 encode them into the url or use a Post variable instead. Ex: hidden input form type.